# Chamber with semi permeable membrane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

Consider two cases in a chamber in which  gases are filled on both sides of a partition which acts a semi permeable membrane :
1.Hydrogen is filled on one side of the partition and it can move through the semi permeable membrane.Hence it will flow till the pressures on both sides are equal.
2.Next,I have hydrogen on one side and oxygen on another.Oxygen cannot penetrate the membrane,but hydrogen is allowed.Still it is observed that hydrogen flows till it's partial pressure becomes same on both sides.
Why does it happen like that in the second case?Why do the oxygen molecules not contribute in stopping the hydrogen molecules from diffusing into the semi permeable membrane?

Comment: It may slow down the rate of equilibration, but at final equilibrium the partial pressure of the hydrogen with be the same on both sides of the membrane.

Answer (score 0):

You can explain this using thermodynamics. I’ll call $A$ the compartment containing oxygen and hydrogen, $B$ the compartment containing only hydrogen. Since you can have an exchange of hydrogen across the membrane, equilibrium is given by equalizing the chemical potential on either side. Assuming an ideal mixture of gas, the chemical potential of hydrogen is:
$$
\mu=\mu^0(T)+RT\ln p
$$
with $p$ the partial pressure of hydrogen. Thus, assuming that the membrane is diabatic so that the temperature is the same on either side, the partial pressures equalize.

Note that if the hydrogen stayed put, the extra presence of oxygen lowers the partial pressure. Thus you need to increase the partial pressure of hydrogen in $A$ and decrease it in $B$. This can can be done by displacing hydrogen from $B$ to $A$. Thus oxygen “attracts” hydrogen (osmosis).

For your last question, the formulation is a bit vague. If you were talking about rates, thermodynamics only considers final states and kinetically, you’d expect the system to relax to this equilibrium state as Chet Miller commented.

You could have also meant to explain the influence of oxygen in the rate of diffusion of hydrogen through the membrane. Intuitively, oxygen impedes the flow from $A$ to $B$ (partly blocks the hydrogen). Quantitatively, the flow is proportional to the difference in partial pressure (analogue of Ohm’s law). Thus, since the input of oxygen decreases the partial pressure, you’ll have a net flow to the left giving a negative feedback loop until the partial pressures balance (like for a RC circuit).

Hope this helps.